# Let A be a simple subgroup of a group G and N be a normal subgroup of G. Show that the only normal subgroups of AN containing N, are N and AN.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

By definition, since $A$ is simple, it contains only itself and ${e}$. If $A$ only contains itself then a subgroup $A$ of $AN$ cannot contain $N$ because there are no common elements between $A$ and $N$?

I'm not sure if I understand what the key to this proof is. I feel like a proof by contradiction might work here.

Suppose A is a subgroup of AN containing N, then $\exists$ n $\in$ N, such that n $\in$ A. However, A is simple, so this is a contradiction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself by talking about a subgroup $A$ of $AN$ containing $N$. You need to consider a normal subgroup $B$ of $AN$ containing $N$ (i.e. call it something different from $A$).

Comment: Hmm, the reason why I'm considering A of AN containing N is because A of AN is the only subgroup of AN that does not contain N(aka. the odd one out). I'm assuming that I will have to prove that the subgroups N and AN contain N later too.

Comment: You are considering the subgroup $A$ containing $N$ because it does not contain $N$???

Comment: Wouldn't I have to prove that the statement holds, that A does not contain N? Since it was stated that : "the only normal subgroups of AN containing N, are N and AN", so A does not contain N, then after I prove that, I will prove separately that N and AN contain N? I apologize if this makes no sense, I'm trying to understand the concept behind this proof.

Comment: $N$ and $AN$ obviously contain $N$, so that is no problem. But you have to prove that there are no other normal subgroups of $G$ that contain $N$, not just $A$. There could in theory be other subgroups like that - but you have to prove that there are not.

Comment: Oh I understand now. Thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $N$ is different from $A$. Hint: $AN/N \cong A/(A \cap N)$. But $A \cap N$ is normal in $A$, so ....

Comment: Why do you need to assume that $N \ne A$? That would just mean $AN=N$.

Comment: If $A \cap N$ is normal in A, this implies that for any common element between A and N, $x(A \cap N)x^{-1} = A \cap N$, for some x $\in$ G? I'm having trouble understanding how normality plays a role.

Comment: @Squires McGee - $A \cap N$ is normal in the simple $A$, so either $A \cap N =1$ or $A \cap N=A$. The latter case is equivalent to $A \subseteq N$ and then $AN=N$ and the statement is trivially true. So $A \cap N=1$. That means $AN/N$ is a simple group.

Comment: @Derek - yes formally you are right, but then the whole statement of the OP becomes rather trivial.